# plist not copied into the application bundle

Tags: iphone, ios, plist

I want to copy a plist into my application bundle with Xcode 4.5.2 (or 4.6).

I select the my.plist, drag it into the project, and make sure its also in the 'Copy Bundle Items' phase in 'Build Phases'. Nothing red, everything is fine.

When I now compile the project, the my.plist is not copied to the application bundle.I've been trying since hours now.

If I now rename the file to my.png, pull the file to Xcode, everything is fine - the my.png file is in the application bundle.

So: why isn't the my.plist file copied to the application bundle but the my.png file?

Any insight is much appreciated.

EDIT:
Thanks for your thoughts! It appears to that there is some strange problem with this project. Any onther (new) project will work as expected here. By changing the extension from 'plist' to 'plis' everything works fine (well, a workaround I know).

Comment: is your file in the bundle member of the current target?

Comment: @holex: do you mean the targets 'copy bundle items' list?

Comment: not exaclty, when you select a file from the bundle and open the _Utilites_ -> _Show File Inspector_ panel, there is a section named _Target Membership_. the question is, the selected file is part of the current target (checkmark shows there) or not.

Comment: thanks holex, good point! Everything right there...

Comment: the .plis fix worked for me as well.  THere must be some strange xcode setting or legacy "feature" that doesn't copy plists as bundle files.  Probably something special about the Info and Entitlements plist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the target membership of the file if you have more than one target in your project. If that doesn't do the trick, copy the actual file into your project's directory via Finder and then add it to the project by selecting "add files to..." from within the Xcode project browser.

Answer (score 1):

- Go to your Project folder
- Locate your plist
- Drag it into your Project (or right-click -> Add files... from Xcode)
- In the window that will be shown, select "Create groups for any added folders" and Add to targets -> select your Target's name. If you have the pList away from your project folder, select "Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)
- Perform a clean build (<kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>) and clean build folder (<kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>)
- Delete your app from Simulator (or Device)
- Go to your project's targets -> Build phases -> Copy bundle resources -> Click the little "+" in the bottom left corner and make sure your pList is being added there
- Build and run the project to see if it has been successfully copied